# Why does 'related_names' make my field required?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am working with Django and Django rest_framework to create a simple API. I have 2 models: a Game model and a Rating model. The models are listed below

```
class Game(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=400)

    def numOfRatings(self):
        return len(Rating.objects.filter(game=self))

    def avgRating(self):
        ratings = Rating.objects.filter(game=self)
        sum = 0
        for rating in ratings:
            sum += rating.stars
        if len(ratings) > 0:
            return sum/len(ratings)
        else:
            return 0


# creating ratings for a movie
class Rating(models.Model):

    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  related_name='ratings') # rating for a specific game
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # user that the rating is tied too
    # user is imported from Django's user model

    stars = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(5)])

    # making it so each user-movie combination can only have one entry in this model
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user','game'))
        index_together = (('user','game'))
```

The rating model contains game as a foreign key. The issue is that when I try to create a game object via a post request, I get

```
{
    "ratings": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

Now, when I remove the `related_name='ratings'` everything is fixed and I can create Games through post requests. Why can't I create new Game objects without any ratings? ratings is not a field in games. It is related through the foreign key in Ratings. Any advice would be helpful. Thanks!

Edit:

Here is my serializer for both classes as well

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Game, Rating

class RatingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Rating
        fields = ['id','stars','user','game']

class GameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ratings = RatingSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = ['id','title','description','ratings','numOfRatings','avgRating']
```

Comment: Share your serializer. If you override fields, then Django by default makes these required.

Comment: `ratings = RatingSerializer(many=True)` is the only part of the code that edits ratings. I included `related_names = ratings` so that I could use it in the game serializer. Could either of those be causing the issue?

Comment: Why do your fields from `GameSerializer` contain `'ratings','numOfRatings','avgRating' `?

Comment: I included those fields so that when I make a GET request on the API, I'll be able to see that information in the response

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem. like Willem Van Onsem aluded to, the line `ratings = RatingSerializer(many=True)` was the culprit. When I create a POST request on the viewset that uses my Gameserializer, the viewset validates my data with the serializer:

```
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

`serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)` Will return false because when the serializer checks all of the fields passed into it, the rating field is null. To remedy the situation, I added a required option to the ratings field: `ratings = RatingSerializer(many=True, required=False)`

TLDR:
`ratings = RatingSerializer(many=True)` made the ratings required. Change it to `ratings = RatingSerializer(many=True, required=False)`